# Angular 2 in spring tools suite

Tags: java, eclipse, angular, typescript, spring-tool-suite

As you know a week ago Google released a official version of Angular 2. I want to setup my STS to create Angular2/typescript projects. I read some article but I'm not pretty sure which is the best way to do it.

Can you give me some advices what should I install to be able to write Angular 2 / Typescript in STS?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since STS is an Eclipse-based package, you can install regular Eclipse plugins into it. For AngularJS I would recommend to use https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: But this is angular 1 not angular 2

Comment: Yes it's for angular1, for angular2, please install https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started and I suggest you that you use AngularCLI support https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/AngularCLI to generate your project, components